# Where do games store temporary data and is there a way to access it with python? "AI" coding

Tags: python, collections, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, training-data

Not sure what I'm trying to do is actually called. But according to my understanding in the matter, games use some sort of temporary memory when displaying content. Like how many kills you have, what you score is and at the end of the match, if you won of lost. How do games store this sort or information, is it in the RAM, and in what coding language? Or does it depend on the game? The game I'm trying to do this in is called IronSight.

I'm gonna use this information to determine whether or not my *AI* will keep its previous game as training data or not.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: "Temporary memory" is just called "memory". Or "RAM". Or "the heap". Almost all programs, including almost all games, keep all kinds of things there. You don't need any "coding language" for it; you just use values of the appropriate types from your programming language and program. I think you need to read a basic tutorial on programming before you start  working on building an AI.

Comment: Knowing that something is stored in RAM will not help you at all to access it. If there is a way to access the information, then this depends on the game.

Comment: I have quite some coding knowledge, enough to make a Neural Network atleast. But I'm still wondering how you actually acces the memory, is there a built-in function in python or a python module for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cheat Engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/) to figure out how a game works and make modifications to it. This does not work on online games. You can disassemble the memory of the process and figure out where the displayed content is stored in memory.

> [...]  does it depend on the game?

Of course does it depend on the game. I don't know IronSight, but as mentioned in the comments, these information must be stored in the RAM. Otherwise the game would not run. So the only advise I can give you is to have a look at Cheat Engine and try to figure out where in the RAM the Information is stored.